# How to assign field values to a constructor in Apex Test Class?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I am trying to test my custom controller's `saveNewContact()` method. I am trying to set the fields on the page, or in the constructor contact, and attempt to save the record. Unfortunately, when I run my test class, My system debug is showing that the constructor's contact last name is `null` and an error message saying

> "Key value cannot be null."

I am thinking that I am not assigning the value to the constructor correctly.
I have the following custom controller for a VF page:

```
public with sharing class DonorSearchCon {
  public Contact con {get;set;}

     public DonorSearchCon() {      
        con = new Contact();
        System.debug('LastName Test: ' +con.LastName);
    }

    public pageReference newExistingContactButton(){
        con.FirstName = result.firstName;

       PageReference newContactRecord = Page.NewContactGMS;
       return newContactRecord;
   }

    public pageReference saveNewContact(){
        if(con.LastName == '' || con.LastName == null){
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Please provide Last Name');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
            return null;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
public static testMethod void testSaveNewContact(){
    donorSearchCon controller = new donorSearchCon();        
    controller = new donorSearchCon();

    Contact cont = new Contact();

   PageReference pageRef = Page.NewContactGMS;
   Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
   pageRef.getParameters().put('cont.LastName', 'Test');

    Test.startTest();
         controller.saveNewContact();        
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

VF Page:

```
   <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_horizontal">
      <span class="slds-form-element__label">Last Name</span>
          <div class="slds-form-element__control">
              <abbr class="slds-required" title="required">*</abbr>
                  <apex:inputText value="{! con.LastName }"/>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where are you declaring your `con` variable in the `DonorSearchCon` class?

Comment: You must be having a class level attribute for `Contact` which you must have used in visualforce page, you should assign value to that property in test class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is not the correct way to set fields on the `Contact`:

```
pageRef.getParameters().put('cont.FirstName', 'Test');
```

Instead, simply reference the property on your controller:

```
controller.con.FirstName = 'Test';
```

Obviously, you would follow the same pattern to set `LastName`.

Comment: +1, was trying to understand why he has put that statement from 10 min, :-P

Comment: Thank you for the info. That is what did it. I guess the scenarios on how to test my VF page controller on the net mislead me. Thanks